# Bibliography in the following text?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

In the following text I don't get bibliography citation. I want `Fricker (1995: 396--7)` in the body of the text to be a hyperlinked to the bibliography at the end of the document.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\journal{Journal Name}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{\textbf What there is}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Prelude}
\label{S:1}
It is \footnote{that can be found in \cite{Fricker(1995: 396--7)} in the recent decades, the awareness about the political role.}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Fricker(1995: 396--7)} Fricker, E. (1994). Against gullibility. In B. K. Matilal \& A. Chakrabarti (eds.), \textit{Knowing from words} (pp. 125-61). Dordrecht: Kluwer Academic Publishers.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cite` package causes the problem, So please add more code to show what you need from this package (this will help to find alternatives)

Comment: @koleygr The question is refined here: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396104/hyperref-to-the-reference-in-the-mentioned-text