# Hyperref to the reference in the mentioned text

Tags: hyperref

I want "Smith (2003: 22-3)" in the footnote to appear as a hyperlink to the same reference mentioned in the bibliography section. How should I do that?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{Title}}


\begin{abstract}
this is abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\hspace{-0.5cm} social epistemology, testimony, manipulation, truth, knowledge
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{one}
That is widely accepted.\footnote{for example see Smith (2008: 22-3) as one example.}

\section{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem Smith, D. (2003). Perception. Oxford University press.  

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use hyperref command and a label in the bibitem (after a `\phantomsection` command):

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{Title}}


\begin{abstract}
this is abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\hspace{-0.5cm} social epistemology, testimony, manipulation, truth, knowledge
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{one}
That is widely accepted.\footnote{for example see \hyperref[firstbibitem]{Smith (2008: 22-3)} as one example.}


\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{bib1}\phantomsection\label{firstbibitem} Smith, D. (2003). Perception. Oxford University press.  

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user157323.. Check the edited code... You need a phantomsection before the label

Comment: There comes extra text by this code. How should I remove the extra text?

Comment: what do you mean extra text?

Comment: if you mean the random text it is the \lipsum command just before bibliography section. I added that to let you check that the link works. But the \phantomsection is needed for more references than one and doesn't adds text

Comment: I compile it and there is this piece of text showing out of nowhere, about 15 paragraphs.

Comment: @user157323... It is the `\lipsum[1-10]` command... It adds random text to let you check things... just remove it. Also remove the `\usepackage{lipsum}` just before \begin{document}...